# append items from shuffled list to a new list

Tags: python, list, random, append, shuffle

For a text classification project (age) I'm making a subset of my data. I've made 3 lists with filenames, sorted by age. I want to shuffle these lists and then append 5000 filenames from each shuffled list to a new list. The result should be a data subset with 15000 files (5000 10s, 5000 20s, 5000 30s). Beneath you can see what I wrote so far. But I know that [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) returns none and a none type object is not iterable. How can I solve this problem?

```
def seed():
   return 0.47231099848

teens = [list of files]
tweens = [list of files]
thirthies = [list of files]
data = []
for categorie in random.shuffle([teens, tweens, thirthies],seed):
    data.append(teens[:5000])
    data.append(tweens[:5000])
    data.append(thirthies[:5000])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that `random.shuffle` returns None. That's because it shuffles its list argument in-place, and it's a Python convention that functions which take a mutable arg and mutate it return `None`. However, you misunderstand the `random` arg to `random.shuffle`: it needs to be a random number generator, not a function like your `seed` that always returns the same number.

BTW, you can seed the standard random number generator provided by the random module using its `seed` function. `random.seed` accepts any hashable object as its argument, although it's customary to pass it a number or string. You can also pass it `None` (which is equivalent here to not passing it an arg at all), and it will seed the randomiser with the system random source (if there isn't a system random source then the system time is used as the seed). If you don't explicitly call `seed` after importing the random module, that's equivalent to calling `seed()`

The benefit of supplying a seed is that each time your run the program with the same seed the random numbers produced by the various random module functions will be exactly the same. This is *very* useful while developing and debugging your code: it can be hard to track down errors when the output keeps on changing. :)

---

There are two main ways to do what you want. You can shuffle the lists and then slice the first 5000 file names from them. Or you can use the `random.sample` function to take 5000 random samples. That way you don't need to shuffle the whole list.

```
import random

random.seed(0.47231099848)

# teens, tweens, thirties are lists of file names
file_lists = [teens, tweens, thirties]

# Shuffle
data = []
for flist in file_lists:
    random.shuffle(flist)
    data.append(flist[:5000])
```

Using `sample`

```
# Sample
data = []
for flist in file_lists:
    data.append(random.sample(flist, 5000))
```

---

I haven't performed speed tests on this code, but I suspect that `sample` will be faster, since it just need to randomly select items rather than moving all the list items. `shuffle` is fairly efficient, so you probably wouldn't notice much difference in the run time unless your teens, tweens, and thirties file lists each have a lot more than 5000 file names.

Both of those loops make `data` a nested list containing 3 sublists, with 5000 file names in each sublist. However, if you want it to be a flat list of 15000 file names you just need to use the `list.extend` method instead of `list.append`. Eg,

```
data = []
for flist in file_lists:
    data.extend(random.sample(flist, 5000))
```

Or we can do it using a list comprehension with a double `for` loop:

```
data = [fname for flist in file_lists for fname in random.sample(flist, 5000)]
```

---

If you need to filter the contents of `data` to build your final file list, the simplest way is to add an `if` condition to the list comprehension.

Let's say we have a function that can test whether a file name is one we want to keep:

```
def keep_file(fname):
    # if we want to keep fname, return True, otherwise return False
```

Then we can do

```
data = [fname for flist in file_lists for fname in random.sample(flist, 5000) if keep_file(fname)]
```

and `data` will only contain the file names that pass the `keep_file` test.

Another way to do it is to create the file names using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension and then pass that to the built-in `filter` function:

```
data_gen = filter(keep_file, (fname for flist in file_lists for fname in random.sample(flist, 5000)))
```

`data_gen` is itself an iterator. You can build a list from it like this:

```
data_final = list(data_gen)
```

Or if you don't actually need all the names as a collection and you can just process them one by one, you can put it in a `for` loop, like this:

```
for fname in data_gen:
    print(fname)
    # Do other stuff with fname
```

This uses less RAM, but the downside is that it "consumes" the file names, so once the `for` loop is finished `data_gen` will be empty.

Let's assume that you've written a function that extracts the desired data from each file:

```
def age_and_text(fname):
    # Do stuff that extracts the age and desired text from the file
    return fname, age, text
```

You could create a list of those `(filename, age, text)` tuples like this:

```
data_gen = (fname for flist in file_lists for fname in random.sample(flist, 5000) if keep_file(fname))

final_data = [age_and_text(fname) for fname in data_gen]
```

---

Notice the slice in my first snippet: `flist[:5000]`. That takes the first 5000 items in `flist`, the items with indices 0 to 4999 inclusive. Your version had `teens[:5001]`, which is an off-by-one error. Slices work the same way as ranges. Thus `range(5000)`yields the 5000 numbers from 0 to 4999. It works this way because Python (like most modern programming languages) uses zero-based indexing.

Comment: Is it correct that when I execute that code, the result is a nested list consisting of a list per categorie? Because  `print(len(data))` gives 3 as a result.

Comment: @Lorien Yes, it creates a nested list containing 3 sublists, with 5000 filenames in each sublist. I assumed you wanted that because of the code you posted in your question. But it's very easy to change it so it produces a flat list of 15000 file names. I'll add some more code to my answer.

Comment: Yes, a flat list would be better I guess, because I have to loop over it again to make a definite data list which consists of the info I take out of the files.

Comment: thank you, but my files are xml files, so the final list should be a list that takes the age and text out of the xml tree per file and puts it in a list. That's the next step for me to figure out

Comment: @Lorien You can still use my code, you just need to put the correct logic in the `keep_file` function. If you need help writing the XML processing code you should ask a fresh question. Your new question can contain a link to this one (and vice versa) to let people know that it's a follow-on question.

Comment: @Lorien I guess you want the final list to be a list of (filename, age, text) tuples. Once you've extracted the age and text data, that's pretty easy to do, as my latest update shows.

Comment: Careful with seeding the RNG with arbitrary objects and expecting the same results: things change when you change Python versions or CPU architectures (and some hashes -- e.g. of strings -- are randomized in Python 3).

Comment: @MariusGedminas Good points. Notice that I said that you _can_ use any hashable object as the seed, but I didn't say it was a good idea. ;) FWIW, I'm not happy that you can't run the same code on Python 2 & 3 that uses a fixed string or integer seed and get the same results, as I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41955452/4014959).

Answer (score 9):

First problem is that you are shuffling the list consisting of the 3 items [teens, tweens, thirthies] (even each of the item is a list) instead of  shuffling each sublist

Second, you may use `random.sample` instead of `random.shuffle`

```
for categ in [teens, tweens, thirthies]:
    data.append(random.sample(categ,5000])
```

or as @JonClements suggested in the comments you can use the **list comprehension**

```
categories = [teens, tweens, thirthies]
data = [e for categ in categories for e in random.sample(categ, 5000)]
```

Comment: @JonClements the list comprehension gave me exactely what I wanted: a list of 15000 randomly chosen files, with 5000 per category. This really helped me

Comment: @JonClements every time you run the list comprehension, the samples change, I guess. My next step is to make a list with info I take from the files in the subset list. But when I run a for-loop on the subset list, I now get a name error: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: to get the same samples each time simply add ``random.seed(0.47231099848)`` after your ``import random`` as explained by @PM 2Ring

Answer (score 5):

[`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) returns `None`, which is not iterable

you should do

```
data = []
for category in [teens, tweens, thirthies]:
    category_copy = category[:]
    random.shuffle(category_copy, seed)
    data.append(category_copy[:5000])
```

Comment: this will append `5001` elements from each list! Use `category_copy[:5000]` instead

Comment: There's no need to copy the lists, since the OP doesn't mind if the original lists are shuffled. OTOH, it's probably more efficient to use `sample` rather than `shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` changes list itself (makes it shuffled). So looks like you want something like this:

```
teens = [list of files]
tweens = [list of files]
thirthies = [list of files]
random.shuffle(teens)
random.shuffle(tweens)
random.shuffle(thirthies)
data = []
for categorie in [teens, tweens, thirthies] :
    data.append(categorie[:5000])
```

BTW `somelist[:n]` will be truncated to `n` elements, check this:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][:3]
[1, 2, 3]
```